# wp-super-cache exclude file from caching

Tags: cache, plugin-wp-supercache

Is there any mean to exclude a `*.php` file to [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)?
I've in my `single.php` page an `include news.php`, the file `news.php` contains ten links to my last articles.

So I want to cache `single.php` but to exclude `news.php` that is included in `single.php`.

It is possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Old way was with `mfunc()`, but there is a new way: [The shiny new dynamic content in WP Super Cache](http://ocaoimh.ie/2013/10/21/shiny-new-dynamic-content-wp-super-cache/). Try it out and report back in an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than incorporating [dynamic content into cached pages](http://ocaoimh.ie/2013/10/21/shiny-new-dynamic-content-wp-super-cache/), you are better off using AJAX to pull dynamic content onto those pages in the browser.

In your `news.php` file, simply have an empty element that will contain the content. Better still, have it contain an [AJAX spinner](http://ajaxload.info/) that indicates that content is coming.

```
<div id="late-load-news">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to load your news content -- this code goes in your theme's functions.php:

```
/**
* AJAX handler to output an HTML fragment for news
*/
function wpse_70813_news() {
    // stop browser from caching output
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');

    //...output your news content here...

    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_late-load-news', 'wpse_70813_news');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_late-load-news', 'wpse_70813_news');

/**
* enqueue jQuery
*/
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
});

/**
* add footer script to load news
*/
add_action('wp_print_footer_script', function() {
    ?>

    <script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        dataType : "html",
        data : { action: "late-load-news" },
        success : function(content) {
            jQuery("#late-load-news").html(content);
        }
    });
    </script>

    <?php
});
```

That will load the content every time a visitor navigates to a new page. If your news content doesn't change much, I recommend you make use of [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) to cache the news content in the browser for the duration of the visit. If you want to limit how long that cache lasts, see [Session storage with expiry time](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/session-storage-with-expiry-time/).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to prevent caching of the `news.php` file:

1. Visit the WP Super Cache settings page in your WordPress administration dashboard *(Settings > WP Super Cache)*.
2. Visit the 'Advanced' tab along the top of that page
3. Scroll down to the **Accepted Filenames & Rejected URIs** heading
4. Look for the box with the description of:

   > Add here those filenames that can be cached, even if they match one of the rejected substring specified above.
5. Enter `news.php` on a new line in the textbox below the description
6. Click **Save Files »**

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this, doesn't change :(
my list isn't dynamically  generated :/